# Запретить окончание строки на определенную подгруппу

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Имеется такая регулярка (js):

```
^\w{2}\d{5}$
```

Как можно модернизировать ее таким образом, чтобы запретить окончание строки на группу из 3-х нулей подряд?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать блоки предварительного просмотра вперёд или назад:

```
^\w{2}\d{5}$(?<!000)
^(?!.*000$)\w{2}\d{5}$
```

См. [демо №1](https://regex101.com/r/twvSEI/1) и [демо №2](https://regex101.com/r/twvSEI/2).

Блок предварительного просмотра назад `(?<!000)` осуществляет проверку по достижении конца строки, блок предварительного просмотра вперёд `(?!.*000$)` делает это в самом её начале. Пока что не все среды JS поддерживают блоки предварительного просмотра назад, поэтому, если необходима поддержка во всех браузерах, используйте второй вариант.

Comment: или так :) `^\w{2}\d{2}(?!000$)\d{3}$`

Comment: @splash58 Я старался показать универсальный вариант. Можно, конечно, и так.

Comment: Я же не  вместо вашего решения, а так, как вариант :)

Comment: Вот интересно, про первое я бы и не придумал, самым очевидным выглядит второй, но дебаггер на regex101 говорит, что он самый неэффективный

Comment: @splash58 Ни у одного из выражений, перечисленных выше, нет проблем с "эффективностью", все они в реальной жизни не вызовут каких-либо проблем  с производительностью.